# Which one is correct? Whose or who

Tags: difference

I am an intelligent and independent man whose doesn't need any help.

Or

I am an intelligent and independent man who doesn't need any help.

If both is correct, then what is the difference between them.

Feel free to correct my any sentences. Thank you! :)

Comment: The pronoun is subject of the relative clause, and thus it should be nominative "who".

Comment: _Whose_ would need to refer to something belonging to the man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"whose" is the *possessive* form of "who":

- "I" --> "my"
- "he" --> "his"
- "who" --> "whose"

Therefore, it generally needs a noun to be possessed:

> Whose **ball** is this?
>   I am a man whose **arms** are strong.

"Who" is the *nominative* (subject) form, so it should be used anywhere you need a subject for a sentence or a clause:

> I am an intelligent and independent man.  **I** don't need any help.
>   I am an intelligent and independent man **who** doesn't need any help.